# Why do concrete levees break?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science

I saw a picture of a breach in a levee that was constructed from vertical concrete slabs. I do not see why this should break when overflowed. Levee flood walls not as wide as normal levees build from sand, earth, clay and gravel. I understand why and how normal levees fail, even from a minimal initial breach only few centimeters deep. But in concrete, a small breach would not grow, and not happen in the first place.

Overflow is not the problem I mean - of course that may happen if the concrete wall is not high enough.

A trivial failure mode would be to simply topple over, of course. I assume that is not the case, as making it not do that is the whole point to build it. Overflow could be involved in creating a breach. It could erode the foundation if that is build in a way allowing that.

Why does a strong wall of concrete not withstand water?

For an example of a wall failing in New Orleans during huricane Katrina, see ["Mega Disasters - Hurricane Katrina full video" at 3m 19s](https://youtu.be/08GLRweR3sw?t=3m17s) - the video shows [other examples](https://youtu.be/08GLRweR3sw?t=2m04s).

Comment: Water seeping underneath, undermining the foundation? Maybe also due to burrowing animals? More a civil engineering question.

Comment: That could be an answer!

Comment: What's wrong with the answers in the video that you linked?  The show in some detail why those walls failed. (Largely due to the weakness of the dirt in which they were anchored, to state it in very short summary.)

Comment: @Brick Oops, seems like I stopped watching it too soon. I like asking questions I can answer myself partially to add it the general corpus of StackExchange - this was not intentional one of them. Make an answer from it if you like!

Answer (score 2):

The video linked by the OP eventually (much further into it than noted) goes into some detail of multiple failure modes encountered in the New Orleans hurricane disaster.  They mostly have to do with the low-quality soil over which the walls were built, with note for the fact that the contemporary concrete walls are in many cases built over dirt levees that date back to the 1700s.

Some specific failure modes discussed:

1. Water flowing over the top of concrete walls dropped with significant force on the city-side of the wall.  This dug out the dirt behind the wall in some cases, leaving it without support to resist the water pressure on the high, Gulf side.  Those segments fell over.
2. In some cases pressure from the storm surge pushed unusual amounts of water into the soil, including the soil under the walls.  When this happened deeper into the ground than the wall supports had been driven, the underlying land itself slide inland, taking the wall with it.  In these cases, the wall segments themselves did not "fail" in the usual sense but were floated away with everything else.  Of course where some segments floated away but adjacent sections did not, you got a breach.

Complicating factors also include that the entire city of New Orleans and its surrounding is sinking due to the same issues with the underlying soil.  The natural process of the river delta had included regular flooding dropping new silt into areas that had dried out and sunk. The river's course through the delta also, prior to being constrained, would change from time to time, which again tended to drop more silt into lower areas.  Now water is being compressed out of the land under the city over time and dried out of other areas, but nothing comes through to bring the height back up.  This means there are more places, over time, for increased water pressures to build or water to flow.